# My front rotor seems to be making a grinding noise, I have a relatively new bike and I’m not sure what’s causing it

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

I’m new to cycling and I have a road bike with hydraulic disc brakes. I noticed that they are making a quiet, but audible grinding noise. I’ve heard this noise before and since I have a new bike, could this noise be caused by the brake pads needing to be bedded in? When I heard it the first time, it was much louder and then it started to dial down a bit. Anyone know what could be causing this? Thanks

Comment: Does this noise happen all the time? If not, when? What brakes do you have?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the brake caliper is not aligned properly. It is a simple procedure described in this video by park tool

[How to Align a Hydraulic Disc Brake on a Bike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk_nC9anQcM)

Comment: Since it is a new bike, have you bedded-in the brake pads properly on the first rides? The rear brake could be noisy as well but that could be overheard because you 'trail' the noise.

Comment: I have done a decent amount of riding on the bike, probably around 120-130 miles so far, I’ll probably attempt to do the brake alignment procedure and if that doesn’t work, I’ll assume that it’s the brake pads needing to be needed in. I have shimano hydraulic disc brakes, and yes, so far it does happen all the time.